# Forwarding port to remote server?

Tags: iptables, forwarding

How can I forward a local port to a remote host/port?

I have tried using:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <PORT> -j DNAT --to-destination <DESTINATION_SERVER>:<DESTINATION_PORT>
```

Comment: Without being able to test right now, this looks good. Why don't you think it works?

Answer (score 5):

There's an important caveat in `DNAT` port forwarding:

- to forward traffic *from an external origin* to a remote port, the iptables `DNAT` rule should be in the `PREROUTING` chain, exactly as you specified.
- but to forward *locally originated* traffic to a remote port, you'll need a similar rule in the `OUTPUT` chain of the `nat` table.

So, if you want all traffic (both locally-generated and incoming traffic) that is going to a specific local port to go to a remote server instead, you'll need two rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <PORT> -j DNAT --to-destination <DESTINATION_SERVER>:<DESTINATION_PORT>
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport <PORT> -j DNAT --to-destination <DESTINATION_SERVER>:<DESTINATION_PORT>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for exactly this! 
If I want to change or remove either port forwarding rule later, would you know how to go about that?

Comment: Note that using the options of the `iptables` command, you can both `-A`ppend and `-I`nsert rules. The `-I` option takes the rule number the new rule will become, pushing any existing rules at that slot and after towards the end of the chain. So, use `iptables --line-numbers -Lnv -t nat` to view the line number of the rule you wish to change. Let's say you want to change rule number #2 in the PREROUTING chain: then just insert a new version of the rule with `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 2 <new rule specification>`, then remove the old one with `iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 3`.

Comment: @RocketNuts also, note that manually inserted iptables rules won't automatically persist over a reboot, unless your distribution includes a specific mechanism to save the current rules at shutdown and restore them after a reboot.

Comment: Thanks, and good point about the rules not being saved over a reboot. This surprises me actually, in this way it's different than `ufw` rules. Is there a way to make these iptables rules permanent? (i.e. persistent over reboot)

Comment: @RocketNuts usually there is some place to store the rules that are meant to be persistent, or a mechanism/service that persists them for you, but the exact details depend on the distribution you're using. On older RHEL and related distributions (newer ones use `firewalld` and you should use it instead of "raw" `iptables`, or disable firewalld if you wish to use `iptables-save`) `iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables` would have been the way to store the current rules so that the system would restore them automatically on reboot.